# Image ListView sizing

Tags: vb.net, image, listview, bitmap

I am loading some images into a LargeIcon ListView by dragging and dropping the files in. This all works roughly but I was wondering if there is any way to display the images better - closer to how they are displayed in windows explorer?

This is what the ListView looks like:
[image: listView]

and this is how the same images appear in the explorer
[image: Explorer]

It would be good to stop the images in the listView all being resized to the same size and display them differently so that the portrait ones don't get squashed. Also, the quality of the images seems to have decreased significantly mainly the colour depth. Is there any way to increase the quality? Loading the images does not have to be a particularly fast process as this is just for personal use.

Comment: The LV is not ideal as an image browser rather more for icons.

Comment: @Plutonix Is there another way of displaying images in a similar way that would allow them to be selected to perform certain operations on certain images?

Comment: Of course.  You could use a FlowLayoutPanel with some pictureboxes.  Use a `List(of Class)` to track the images and perform the "certain operations"

Comment: @Plutonix Ok, I'll try that, thanks for the help